# P and T peak detection in the given ECG data using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-science

I have a set of ECG data. In which I had to find the peaks (P,Q,R,S,T). I have referred some sources and identified the Q,R,S peaks and now I am unable to find the P,T peaks. I am totally new to python.

Here is he data:

```
<patient_details>Issac,1972-08-26,47,96,174,9841061134,orbitsystem.ganesh@gmail.com,M,samson,2019-05-23 11:54:30,murthy,1,76,19,0.17,0.108,0.37,0.131807042478</patient_details><ECG data>7193,7539,14310,14364,7414,7353,7557,7184,~7188,7550,14330,14414,7480,7400,7582,7205,~7140,7546,14356,14462,7533,7426,7618,7224,~7192,7550,14371,14494,7558,7436,7634,7231,~7172,7556,14390,14545,7616,7491,7669,7260,~7123,7557,14404,14590,7671,7532,7698,7281,~7172,7578,14396,14624,7703,7555,7718,7283,~7214,7597,14407,14659,7729,7574,7742,7280,~7219,7599,14414,14702,7764,7594,7743,7284,~7217,7604,14414,14729,7794,7604,7740,7283,~7233,7655,14430,14782,7853,7647,7779,7306,~7207,7663,14444,14831,7895,7676,7808,7326,~7292,7673,14427,14848,7889,7653,7769,7313,~7330,7711,14433,14883,7909,7654,7772,7322,~7343,7732,14442,14934,7969,7706,7807,7341,~7315,7735,14450,14987,8043,7771,7837,7360,~7330,7759,14458,15032,8083,7791,7857,7386,~7364,7790,14464,15063,8106,7804,7859,7397,~7364,7799,14474,15097,8161,7838,7873,7413,~7374,7803,14468,15139,8212,7858,7891,7432,~7391,7836,14478,15181,8258,7900,7927,7462,~7405,7840,14459,15195,8278,7932,7950,7476,~7389,7849,14454,15224,8321,7965,7978,7494,~7470,7860,14445,15230,8322,7972,7979,7497,~7430,7895,14454,15267,8344,8006,8020,7518,~7420,7898,14440,15276,8332,7996,8015,7516,~7482,7918,14410,15265,8332,7988,8005,7519,~7536,7956,14404,15279,8339,7998,8026,7539,~7523,7949,14410,15289,8329,8005,8047,7564,~7501,7945,14403,15283,8329,8009,8049,7562,~7533,7970,14392,15283,8321,8017,8068,7577,~7515,7980,14409,15297,8319,8031,8078,7600,~7508,7967,14396,15286,8331,8047,8072,7590,~7582,7967,14362,15257,8336,8041,8072,7583,~7650,7956,14344,15229,8318,8015,8060,7580,~7570,7945,14342,15223,8314,8015,8059,7599,~7529,7966,14355,15229,8321,8041,8085,7628,~7578,7959,14352,15212,8322,8048,8089,7632,~7546,7932,14332,15181,8306,8055,8078,7615,~7494,7943,14325,15160,8291,8057,8069,7616,~7547,7962,14296,15126,8253,8031,8053,7606,~7646,7953,14239,15066,8203,7985,8015,7570,~7539,7955,14249,15057,8196,7989,8031,7602,~7447,7967,14276,15059,8191,8024,8069,7646,~7532,7942,14258,14998,8145,7994,8046,7633,~7543,7932,14220,14927,8073,7949,8011,7594,~7491,7943,14190,14869,8019,7919,7992,7583,~7505,7897,14183,14822,7985,7907,8007,7593,~7470,7858,14176,14778,7940,7889,7991,7584,~7478,7823,14152,14706,7876,7857,7960,7567,~7549,7832,14111,14618,7783,7795,7915,7526,~7456,7792,14132,14556,7723,7756,7910,7515,~7336,7745,14149,14517,7669,7719,7881,7503,~7309,7725,14143,14448,7587,7676,7840,7476,~7350,7701,14117,14364,7496,7624,7798,7432,~7295,7653,14114,14298,7440,7572,7746,7394,~7282,7643,14100,14236,7350,7527,7704,7368,~7296,7626,14081,14174,7284,7491,7688,7345,~7217,7588,14086,14110,7205,7440,7655,7310,~7174,7557,14086,14038,7139,7387,7613,7283,~7209,7512,14081,13995,7087,7351,7578,7274,~7178,7472,14078,13950,7029,7318,7549,7255,~7110,7441,14066,13878,6954,7259,7489,7222,~7076,7420,14076,13839,6896,7223,7485,7225,~7127,7390,14050,13784,6831,7186,7469,7187,~7013,7332,14083,13760,6783,7164,7458,7183,~6996,7308,14078,13712,6725,7128,7417,7170,~7024,7302,14077,13676,6668,7081,7392,7135,~6996,7283,14071,13635,6613,7034,7363,7121,~6940,7247,14067,13593,6553,6998,7349,7102,~6892,7258,14098,13599,6539,7006,7384,7119,~6894,7222,14086,13558,6483,6972,7346,7096,~6920,7193,14064,13510,6437,6926,7301,7050,~6937,7191,14053,13506,6422,6914,7295,7047,~6928,7176,14060,13499,6393,6894,7292,7056,~6855,7155,14077,13482,6384,6899,7281,7061,~6861,7159,14069,13479,6372,6881,7266,7057,~6935,7164,14063,13461,6334,6857,7253,7047,~6935,7140,14047,13443,6303,6828,7218,7027,~6897,7114,14054,13439,6296,6822,7200,7030,~6801,7123,14090,13475,6316,6861,7245,7069,~6763,7123,14087,13484,6316,6870,7268,7087,~6961,7130,14023,13420,6250,6812,7202,7032,~7013,7148,14022,13406,6231,6804,7201,7025,~6947,7131,14057,13437,6247,6835,7236,7053,~6806,7094,14081,13461,6263,6848,7262,7070,~6828,7101,14059,13453,6250,6822,7240,7070,~6870,7118,14054,13451,6256,6817,7249,7073,~6882,7106,14045,13464,6253,6827,7237,7063,~6925,7101,14028,13443,6243,6817,7216,7047,~6954,7111,14036,13458,6254,6831,7224,7050,~6924,7091,14038,13461,6253,6837,7221,7054,~6868,7082,14049,13474,6257,6828,7214,7051,~6866,7107,14052,13495,6271,6838,7231,7069,~6866,7121,14046,13510,6284,6858,7243,7086,~6868,7107,14023,13503,6260,6851,7216,7070,~6976,7097,13991,13465,6223,6817,7162,7037,~6980,7117,13999,13479,6244,6822,7191,7044,~6827,7093,14059,13534,6302,6867,7234,7099,~6831,7094,14064,13540,6302,6854,7217,7102,~6876,7114,14052,13551,6290,6858,7231,7108,~Bv:3,Ld:0000000000,Pm:0,Hs:1,gain1,cld:0,BPM:73,#*#6910,7087,14042,13542,6279,6855,7221,7109,~6869,7066,14036,13540,6277,6850,7210,7105,~6865,7091,14035,13551,6290,6858,7229,7121,~6885,7101,14039,13552,6294,6868,7243,7122,~6872,7094,14050,13564,6312,6877,7231,7118,~6863,7103,14045,13578,6303,6880,7240,7134,~6909,7125,14022,13579,6289,6881,7260,7132,~6890,7117,14001,13561,6292,6888,7256,7119,~6900,7130,13997,13550,6279,6878,7240,7112,~6949,7147,13995,13554,6273,6873,7250,7125,~6861,7145,14018,13585,6313,6904,7265,7160,~6890,7154,13980,13561,6287,6858,7211,7116,~6928,7147,13997,13583,6286,6844,7194,7115,~6904,7152,14015,13594,6309,6858,7218,7137,~6896,7125,14014,13594,6326,6878,7214,7138,~6892,7118,14008,13587,6324,6881,7216,7147,~6897,7121,14022,13603,6324,6886,7236,7147,~6883,7114,14018,13604,6320,6893,7231,7156,~6886,7103,14008,13607,6307,6881,7213,7153,~6975,7124,13966,13578,6294,6861,7198,7138,~6911,7130,13987,13597,6332,6896,7242,7170,~6800,7121,14006,13620,6340,6920,7273,7182,~6889,7140,13974,13589,6310,6899,7259,7160,~6976,7174,13937,13575,6300,6897,7252,7164,~6928,7147,13937,13572,6299,6886,7239,7184,~6935,7142,13949,13568,6293,6858,7230,7184~6852,7000,13799,13558,6294,6748,7240,7158,~6856,7016,13815,13551,6299,6736,7233,7151,~6849,7025,13820,13537,6286,6723,7234,7161,~6848,7029,13815,13544,6274,6729,7234,7156,~6849,7033,13808,13526,6280,6716,7221,7148,~6851,7033,13809,13513,6283,6722,7227,7142,~6845,7026,13815,13517,6290,6725,7231,7160,~6858,7025,13812,13519,6296,6705,7214,7169,~6885,7018,13826,13533,6293,6705,7210,7169,~6952,7031,13820,13521,6293,6684,7200,7144,~6927,7059,13815,13509,6314,6690,7200,7144,~6776,7065,13875,13572,6380,6762,7279,7225,~6883,7090,13865,13552,6367,6740,7279,7228,~6931,7111,13843,13541,6369,6752,7275,7216,~6927,7138,13863,13554,6409,6788,7313,7237,~6962,7174,13847,13537,6412,6781,7329,7232,~6892,7186,13868,13565,6456,6820,7365,7255,~6920,7210,13867,13555,6445,6805,7350,7240,~6846,7246,13896,13586,6485,6848,7401,7270,~6876,7260,13898,13587,6507,6863,7408,7281,~7007,7254,13847,13534,6462,6817,7358,7224,~6951,7274,13853,13548,6470,6830,7366,7251,~6872,7257,13871,13557,6490,6850,7398,7266,~6900,7213,13847,13520,6462,6812,7375,7250,~6923,7222,13820,13514,6449,6804,7360,7248,~6980,7292,13827,13528,6479,6827,7388,7264,~6975,7294,13839,13540,6499,6837,7414,7281,~6941,7278,13827,13531,6502,6837,7405,7280,~7003,7309,13795,13524,6502,6840,7411,7290,~7047,7326,13765,13498,6499,6837,7415,7289,~6992,7331,13755,13506,6502,6851,7442,7316,~7023,7363,13737,13502,6499,6870,7452,7331,~7083,7396,13717,13489,6503,6880,7479,7341,~7085,7383,13720,13510,6522,6880,7481,7347,~7104,7372,13724,13530,6530,6871,7465,7352,~7117,7399,13726,13513,6530,6867,7465,7352,~7058,7380,13720,13482,6532,6887,7476,7358,~7048,7358,13723,13460,6510,6873,7447,7352,~7096,7359,13719,13440,6480,6848,7437,7350,~7107,7335,13709,13419,6476,6838,7447,7365,~7120,7312,13710,13401,6469,6817,7434,7383,~7113,7331,13730,13384,6463,6809,7434,7380,~7048,7326,13764,13366,6445,6801,7431,7374,~6918,7288,13785,13356,6433,6794,7434,7377,~6942,7240,13784,13332,6397,6765,7401,7363,~7014,7216,13789,13288,6366,6730,7384,7354,~6993,7179,13800,13281,6352,6726,7388,7354,~6969,7155,13827,13308,6359,6719,7369,7351,~6949,7148,13850,13329,6380,6720,7382,7350,~6942,7111,13870,13332,6397,6730,7387,7334,~6913,7065,13903,13325,6402,6712,7352,7309,~6916,7063,13929,13321,6393,6697,7333,7284,~6973,7049,13929,13321,6397,6692,7324,7276,~6913,6997,13926,13297,6367,6669,7292,7258,~6899,6991,13919,13256,6319,6636,7269,7251,~6938,7014,13915,13243,6310,6621,7273,7253,~6904,6988,13927,13245,6320,6630,7285,7241,~6900,6950,13923,13231,6296,6610,7250,7215,~6914,6956,13927,13224,6284,6588,7239,7211,~6904,6934,13923,13203,6271,6571,7224,7208,~6749,6892,13960,13220,6290,6604,7253,7231,~6770,6883,13963,13203,6277,6581,7236,7212,~6865,6900,13936,13165,6230,6541,7216,7182,~6851,6898,13953,13177,6227,6539,7210,7187,~6866,6892,13963,13172,6229,6536,7198,7184,~6909,6898,13960,13163,6236,6538,7211,7193,~6806,6869,13984,13189,6273,6574,7240,7218,~6766,6882,13984,13210,6294,6580,7242,7241,~6873,6898,13951,13166,6266,6554,7220,7235,~6873,6893,13949,13149,6261,6546,7224,7235,~6768,6868,13970,13172,6280,6578,7250,7260,~6846,6872,13956,13151,6250,6551,7240,7244,~6924,6855,13946,13133,6221,6546,7236,7238,~6914,6868,13930,13123,6220,6519,7208,7224,~6839,6857,13970,13166,6254,6551,7230,7240,~6813,6861,13995,13190,6303,6614,7287,7271,~6839,6871,13990,13191,6304,6611,7281,7237,~6807,6874,13997,13180,6307,6582,7259,7224,~Bv:3,Ld:0000000000,Pm:0,Hs:1,gain1,cld:0,BPM:73,#*#6849,6889,13985,13155,6293,6562,7231,7198,~6945,6895,13944,13113,6247,6526,7191,7163,~6945,6881,13920,13095,6251,6541,7189,7158,~6848,6893,13963,13148,6306,6600,7250,7224,~6808,6885,13990,13206,6362,6643,7294,7270,~6849,6845,13978,13173,6352,6615,7256,7234,~6849,6830,13987,13162,6346,6592,7229,7228,~6858,6848,14005,13161,6334,6569,7226,7219,~6930,7386,14431,14083,6849,6782,7181,6808,~6983,7427,14431,14089,6862,6788,7205,6817,~6996,7410,14413,14075,6831,6735,7189,6785,~6973,7349,14423,14054,6786,6671,7134,6746,~6899,7349,14465,14100,6825,6710,7163,6775,~6931,7356,14450,14098,6818,6725,7182,6779,~6934,7336,14440,14080,6781,6707,7158,6757,~6940,7360,14442,14051,6755,6694,7146,6746,~6951,7389,14433,14052,6746,6679,7150,6701,~6948,7390,14437,14079,6782,6709,7156,6676,~6985,7400,14452,14086,6782,6710,7133,6669,~6990,7410,14461,14090,6785,6684,7129,6711,~6909,7348,14476,14093,6799,6664,7111,6736,~6880,7311,14482,14115,6791,6653,7089,6734,~6987,7349,14457,14090,6782,6689,7107,6740,~6980,7355,14455,14061,6752,6716,7137,6720,~6983,7353,14448,14068,6751,6733,7176,6721,~7004,7349,14413,14048,6725,6670,7150,6710,~7006,7377,14424,14073,6718,6621,7130,6710,~6942,7386,14442,14072,6728,6648,7127,6734,~6959,7352,14428,14047,6713,6660,7113,6720,~7016,7382,14403,14051,6715,6666,7111,6711,~Bv:3,Ld:0000000000,Pm:0,Hs:1,gain1,cld:0,BPM:73,#*#6969,7438,14417,14097,6738,6689,7153,6765,~6806,7387,14445,14107,6755,6689,7171,6786,~6924,7390,14410,14048,6709,6653,7124,6711,~6999,7410,14413,14058,6716,6666,7129,6705,~6978,7401,14411,14083,6756,6705,7162,6746,~6938,7391,14440,14098,6752,6682,7150,6769,~6971,7410,14454,14118,6748,6651,7131,6767,~6913,7383,14450,14104,6720,6657,7117,6762,~6918,7366,14461,14094,6726,6686,7156,6775,~6983,7359,14457,14101,6735,6692,7173,6779,~6924,7331,14468,14108,6715,6644,7127,6746,~6930,7329,14430,14076,6660,6594,7072,6695,~7047,7394,14403,14072,6642,6592,7087,6708,~7000,7408,14447,14104,6683,6628,7130,6752,~6999,7394,14430,14111,6666,6605,7108,6763,~6928,7386,14450,14132,6669,6585,7101,6770,~6931,7384,14465,14131,6672,6585,7107,6749,~6937,7399,14437,14129,6675,6581,7097,6724,~6961,7384,14426,14110,6672,6571,7076,6698,~6947,7386,14454,14125,6638,6559,7114,6695,~6963,7413,14462,14132,6648,6608,7152,6695,~6972,7408,14466,14121,6636,6565,7110,6665,~6941,7404,14481,14169,6662,6546,7091,6670,~6951,7376,14481,14171,6692,6605,7107,6669,~6928,7311,14479,14136,6685,6587,7056,6647,~6962,7346,14471,14135,6688,6604,7065,6653,~6909,7383,14481,14156,6703,6623,7100,6685,~6914,7331,14469,14141,6640,6585,7065,6641,~7014,7326,14459,14134,6638,6564,7034,6613,~7033,7387,14481,14171,6675,6580,7065,6650,~6928,7379,14516,14193,6710,6597,7102,6712,~6934,7353,14502,14173,6673,6564,7075,6717,~6995,7369,14488,14164,6635,6546,7072,6721,~6930,7373,14513,14159,6646,6578,7104,6740,~6834,7355,14540,14202,6675,6600,7117,6740,~6944,7373,14534,14202,6659,6545,7094,6707,~7021,7369,14524,14183,6629,6522,7092,6702,~7003,7349,14531,14169,6638,6558,7111,6728,~6962,7332,14540,14197,6673,6597,7147,6746,~6956,7321,14547,14204,6685,6624,7160,6753,~6870,7333,14545,14200,6703,6640,7158,6762,~6941,7339,14523,14187,6693,6607,7121,6738,~6996,7352,14533,14186,6703,6595,7114,6728,~6993,7333,14526,14183,6695,6597,7118,6724,~6937,7318,14541,14181,6702,6614,7136,6744,~7011,7358,14529,14170,6696,6620,7142,6756,~6997,7345,14534,14152,6658,6585,7145,6746,~6916,7333,14543,14142,6638,6546,7110,6694,~6858,7356,14543,14153,6683,6585,7108,6668,~6921,7389,14530,14163,6696,6555,7081,6646,~6968,7363,14557,14136,6676,6521,7030,6621,~6956,7318,14598,14132,6649,6529,7031,6604,~6965,7355,14575,14120,6629,6538,7062,6573,~6942,7359,14567,14111,6629,6536,7075,6534,~6940,7355,14578,14122,6650,6516,7046,6549,~6965,7350,14593,14145,6689,6526,7045,6597,~6918,7328,14650,14184,6751,6591,7089,6659,~6899,7302,14647,14187,6755,6600,7075,6666,~6973,7304,14633,14170,6732,6582,7034,6653,~6921,7318,14657,14156,6712,6528,7029,6581,~6954,7324,14639,14131,6665,6472,6995,6566,~6990,7332,14612,14131,6680,6492,7030,6599,~7010,7346,14615,14146,6700,6512,7062,6637,~6958,7342,14654,14174,6713,6535,7101,6678,~6923,7339,14660,14155,6736,6581,7136,6720,~6947,7355,14661,14159,6741,6575,7129,6744,~6976,7345,14660,14184,6779,6578,7126,6778,~6954,7358,14671,14215,6829,6648,7175,6817,~7013,7411,14663,14201,6831,6661,7218,6827,~7044,7444,14661,14195,6815,6683,7260,6809,~6999,7445,14682,14198,6829,6707,7276,6802,~6983,7447,14685,14204,6853,6730,7287,6808,~7090,7526,14653,14200,6871,6740,7288,6792,~7004,7537,14671,14204,6876,6722,7246,6740,~6990,7513,14661,14198,6878,6705,7171,6668,~7072,7540,14646,14205,6878,6687,7143,6650,~7090,7533,14637,14176,6843,6647,7129,6657,~7021,7502,14665,14188,6842,6638,7120,6710,~7064,7509,14647,14160,6836,6611,7098,6708,~7092,7496,14619,14156,6871,6634,7092,6688,~6995,7509,14644,14205,6908,6671,7104,6707,~7035,7549,14660,14208,6909,6663,7110,6728,~7083,7561,14656,14187,6916,6638,7137,6750,~7090,7551,14639,14188,6926,6683,7192,6801,~7081,7560,14606,14174,6896,6710,7205,6827,~7147,7612,14538,14114,6846,6687,7217,6799,~7159,7653,14526,14120,6865,6703,7242,6791,~7119,7660,14530,14159,6905,6738,7265,6820,~7175,7677,14517,14145,6895,6719,7256,6818,~7296,7680,14503,14139,6881,6729,7268,6802,~7169,7642,14514,14135,6931,6804,7307,6830,~7114,7624,14545,14166,6911,6765,7266,6831,~7172,7626,14503,14117,6832,6697,7230,6815,~7202,7643,14496,14087,6816,6690,7229,6830,~Bv:3,Ld:0000000000,Pm:0,Hs:1,gain1,cld:0,BPM:73,#*#7200,7635,14493,14082,6831,6679,7202,6849,~7233,7649,14526,14096,6848,6696,7233,6870,~7155,7624,14545,14097,6856,6712,7275,6895,~7047,7578,14586,14082,6831,6706,7279,6888,~7089,7587,14592,14055,6773,6667,7258,6840,~7113,7604,14578,14049,6749,6680,7266,6814,~7120,7551,14578,14031,6720,6659,7246,6767,~7151,7502,14577,14018,6692,6592,7172,6712,~7124,7469,14598,14034,6713,6603,7159,6679,~7027,7417,14649,14091,6759,6646,7156,6628,~6904,7400,14730,14141,6823,6699,7155,6597,~7041,7413,14688,14083,6766,6653,7078,6502,~7093,7400,14705,14100,6786,6648,7065,6508,~7002,7326,14730,14113,6758,6577,7027,6544,~6973,7283,14718,14069,6676,6493,6959,6536,~6979,7297,14712,14063,6703,6548,6969,6543,~6975,7275,14723,14052,6698,6532,6950,6544,~6987,7256,14754,14054,6679,6496,6946,6556,~7013,7227,14764,14070,6689,6528,6985,6594,~7003,7196,14747,14037,6652,6512,6991,6584,~6910,7183,14753,14051,6639,6521,7005,6571,~7013,7215,14712,14013,6608,6479,6960,6495,~6956,7185,14729,14006,6626,6485,6955,6468,~6913,7154,14760,14009,6630,6483,6955,6487,~6918,7174,14767,13986,6599,6449,6929,6459,~6927,7172,14730,13983,6583,6456,6929,6427,~6909,7181,14739,13993,6596,6486,6933,6401,~6880,7234,14744,13985,6606,6495,6956,6417,~6934,7247,14719,13966,6609,6515,6971,6430,~6907,7199,14730,13972,6650,6544,6988,6459,~6921,7198,14733,13959,6635,6485,6940,6472,~6917,7202,14756,13979,6640,6492,6978,6524,~6859,7175,14775,13992,6656,6536,7027,6586,~6870,7144,14778,13986,6629,6562,7020,6578,~6955,7145,14746,13954,6593,6564,7005,6530,~6951,7166,14757,13983,6616,6562,7005,6502,~6862,7137,14807,14017,6633,6519,6962,6475,~6856,7144,14812,14016,6668,6535,6969,6492,~6869,7162,14809,14021,6680,6549,6975,6498,~6831,7159,14819,14021,6676,6521,6942,6497,~6820,7137,14809,13990,6636,6492,6897,6471,~6863,7137,14777,13969,6605,6479,6901,6447,~6904,7145,14771,13992,6640,6512,6927,6450,~6879,7144,14780,14018,6712,6580,6959,6479,~6913,7124,14795,14048,6752,6575,6946,6476,~6910,7130,14822,14068,6773,6585,6963,6494,~6801,7123,14847,14069,6782,6598,6974,6524,~6822,7140,14870,14068,6732,6557,6955,6521,~6875,7162,14883,14025,6645,6525,6947,6497,~6842,7157,14898,14004,6563,6483,6930,6452,~6766,7159,14939,13997,6510,6466,6887,6388,~6766,7155,14998,14049,6525,6488,6885,6378,~6720,7149,15024,14097,6610,6552,6924,6400,~6791,7144,14996,14181,6808,6679,6962,6417,~6880,7181,15028,14305,7044,6820,7016,6446,~6890,7140,15096,14438,7250,6890,7023,6440,~6806,7036,15145,14560,7444,6949,7018,6437,~6923,7012,15178,14715,7650,7072,7063,6476,~7088,7120,15209,14938,7870,7289,7226,6620,~7241,7249,15259,15286,8262,7627,7453,6802,~7549,7421,15276,15818,8944,8147,7759,7034,~7945,7639,15337,16494,9808,8749,8118,7281,~8163,7823,15410,17124,10720,9366,8480,7539,~8389,8049,15377,17578,11597,9959,8833,7797,~8734,8308,15240,17884,12350,10487,9162,8059,~9117,8603,15032,18160,13094,10985,9518,8344,~9421,8894,14805,18437,13872,11493,9889,8664,~9760,9031,14598,18667,14424,11777,10076,8844,~10026,8855,14437,18673,14585,11702,9967,8766,~9855,8590,14258,18077,14208,11355,9702,8567,~9562,8540,13889,17019,13497,10951,9518,8470,~9349,8410,13652,16181,12739,10347,9188,8301,~9118,7972,13695,15675,11707,9262,8520,7871,~8718,7563,13802,14976,10185,8091,7830,7423,~8210,7295,13815,13948,8419,7134,7305,7054,~7757,7067,13878,13130,6929,6394,6894,6743,~7296,6752,14064,12680,5958,5825,6503,6429,~6940,6571,14304,12446,5323,5416,6213,6155,~6727,6528,14541,12418,4999,5213,6084,6014,~6507,6533,14773,12617,4999,5211,6085,6013,~6352,6525,14931,12832,5087,5283,6110,6030,~6352,6569,15037,12995,5213,5407,6171,6046,~6387,6639,15114,13175,5454,5611,6284,6110,~6357,6702,15152,13378,5785,5870,6440,6220,~6493,6776,15154,13547,6096,6026,6529,6284,~6605,6840,15148,13728,6433,6230,6661,6374,~6617,6869,15117,13851,6680,6384,6769,6456,~6656,6975,15072,13886,6763,6423,6800,6484,~6711,7050,15063,13923,6759,6421,6817,6501,~6715,7101,15061,13972,6719,6419,6827,6534,~6758,7161,15011,13961,6630,6380,6821,6540,~6835,7234,14969,13985,6625,6421,6862,6546,~6880,7280,14914,14002,6656,6522,6911,6546,~6838,7309,14925,14096,6775,6617,6953,6584,~6827,7369,14935,14211,6964,6699,7010,6650,~6917,7393,14901,14268,7089,6740,7018,6647,~6851,7380,14912,14298,7152,6765,7029,6668,~6855,7374,14881,14278,7148,6749,7021,6698,~6894,7391,14874,14261,7111,6713,7030,6731,~6858,7373,14876,14221,7061,6684,7029,6747,~6856,7373,14855,14201,7014,6669,7026,6754,~Bv:3,Ld:0000000000,Pm:0,Hs:1,gain1,cld:0,BPM:73,#*#6807,7372,14877,14215,7024,6703,7062,6773,~6849,7379,14859,14201,7025,6732,7085,6780,~6877,7380,14857,14225,7074,6765,7108,6775,~6882,7399,14877,14274,7122,6775,7110,6780,~6906,7416,14870,14285,7141,6791,7123,6788,~6870,7425,14869,14309,7184,6832,7139,6778,~6886,7434,14870,14305,7172,6814,7121,6747,~6899,7448,14859,14285,7154,6792,7116,6737,~6886,7442,14847,14284,7148,6797,7114,6736,~6962,7431,14819,14259,7117,6766,7071,6697,~6973,7461,14833,14287,7165,6832,7120,6734,~6941,7454,14846,14309,7201,6847,7116,6733,~6794,7435,14886,14365,7242,6841,7116,6765,~6846,7458,14880,14375,7248,6828,7104,6775,~6945,7474,14850,14346,7245,6840,7118,6763,~6930,7465,14842,14327,7267,6867,7129,6776,~6873,7475,14867,14374,7272,6863,7137,6804,~6940,7489,14859,14375,7260,6832,7124,6792,~6938,7449,14855,14386,7284,6858,7140,6795,~6928,7444,14863,14406,7317,6884,7153,6812,~6930,7474,14883,14448,7351,6919,7188,6838,~6897,7455,14888,14465,7370,6943,7200,6838,~6925,7454,14873,14447,7368,6917,7169,6828,~7024,7503,14846,14419,7357,6874,7142,6802,~7033,7519,14831,14433,7367,6900,7145,6802,~6956,7509,14853,14482,7391,6914,7143,6828,~6985,7516,14846,14501,7411,6929,7146,6836,~7006,7551,14855,14515,7458,6970,7166,6863,~6986,7544,14852,14513,7464,6956,7156,6853,~7030,7563,14843,14507,7463,6947,7149,6844,~7038,7588,14866,14539,7510,6973,7163,6857,~7016,7588,14884,14570,7546,6975,7168,6849,~6995,7561,14890,14594,7534,6955,7155,6853,~7017,7540,14890,14590,7513,6963,7171,6860,~7045,7543,14914,14603,7520,6970,7201,6860,~7058,7541,14918,14625,7521,6979,7213,6872,~6982,7550,14950,14683,7589,7039,7263,6905,~7010,7587,14962,14709,7641,7081,7298,6901,~6956,7582,14962,14725,7701,7107,7327,6909,~6982,7584,14943,14730,7689,7085,7308,6902,~7088,7605,14938,14736,7673,7054,7292,6901,~7113,7605,14929,14744,7683,7051,7302,6915,~7027,7608,14962,14789,7727,7095,7330,6963,~7047,7639,14946,14803,7766,7108,7339,6977,~7089,7649,14949,14815,7784,7117,7359,6980,~7061,7624,14987,14869,7840,7169,7404,7011,~7109,7641,14984,14897,7866,7163,7392,7015,~7209,7662,14956,14906,7870,7134,7353,6996,~7214,7655,14979,14942,7896,7157,7358,7003,~7093,7655,15013,15005,7967,7229,7408,7057,~7062,7710,15035,15046,8035,7291,7463,7109,~7165,7707,15007,15059,8052,7287,7462,7083,~7136,7703,15021,15098,8102,7324,7475,7076,~7214,7757,15018,15112,8116,7331,7471,7061,~7213,7792,15015,15154,8149,7360,7507,7069,~7126,7771,15010,15181,8192,7377,7518,7102,~7097,7793,15025,15220,8232,7394,7521,7137,~7195,7806,14994,15224,8253,7422,7544,7132,~7018,7349,13778,14138,6542,6966,7297,7526,~7014,7329,13781,14091,6472,6914,7279,7499,~7009,7305,13774,14054,6422,6894,7252,7470,~7024,7290,13765,14041,6400,6876,7239,7471,~7044,7277,13769,14016,6392,6853,7236,7471,~6993,7239,13778,13976,6317,6811,7195,7418,~6962,7222,13781,13983,6326,6820,7198,7412,~6928,7198,13785,13988,6337,6817,7187,7405,~6885,7233,13806,14002,6354,6824,7201,7426,~6927,7236,13798,14000,6340,6809,7195,7415,~6916,7206,13792,13975,6312,6776,7166,7386,~6901,7215,13798,13968,6302,6765,7160,7384,~6966,7219,13779,13964,6293,6768,7168,7383,~6901,7179,13813,14013,6333,6805,7191,7409,~6896,7174,13820,14011,6327,6779,7176,7399,~7002,7192,13781,13975,6292,6740,7163,7386,~6989,7175,13778,13959,6293,6748,7156,7381,~6885,7172,13810,13981,6324,6784,7191,7410,~6872,7176,13823,14016,6352,6812,7231,7435,~6978,7179,13795,13993,6316,6784,7201,7403,~6951,7174,13795,13997,6312,6778,7192,7396,~6948,7200,13782,13975,6297,6769,7188,7379,~6942,7213,13782,13972,6304,6781,7217,7379,~6909,7185,13784,13976,6316,6791,7214,7370,~6907,7178,13771,13964,6319,6794,7204,7363,~7010,7212,13754,13948,6314,6785,7208,7347,~6968,7219,13755,13955,6317,6788,7217,7339,~6906,7200,13758,13954,6297,6774,7201,7323,~6890,7206,13779,13975,6314,6775,7217,7326,~6949,7179,13767,13955,6317,6788,7211,7312,~6975,7172,13729,13947,6310,6772,7195,7287,~6955,7200,13738,13948,6320,6775,7201,7303,~6934,7210,13771,13964,6326,6785,7224,7310,~6907,7182,13769,13965,6319,6769,7216,7306,~6904,7182,13769,13964,6319,6765,7211,7293,~6942,7202,13761,13964,6323,6779,7224,7300,~6965,7205,13748,13961,6322,6784,7218,7280,~Bv:3,Ld:0000000000,Pm:0,Hs:1,gain1,cld:0,BPM:73,#*#6904,7189,13771,13974,6337,6791,7237,7279,~6948,7198,13755,13969,6344,6784,7231,7271,~6973,7209,13744,13966,6343,6781,7237,7270,~6930,7178,13753,13979,6343,6766,7227,7254,~6931,7189,13751,13971,6344,6768,7221,7247,~6978,7192,13737,13972,6362,6779,7243,7241,~6931,7182,13751,13997,6373,6802,7260,7251,~6927,7203,13731,13985,6359,6786,7233,7234,~6983,7203,13729,13986,6364,6778,7247,7208,~6968,7209,13717,13983,6374,6789,7262,7200,~6928,7192,13716,13990,6377,6799,7253,7200,~6965,7192,13714,14000,6370,6799,7265,7195,~6980,7205,13697,13992,6370,6807,7265,7180,~6944,7192,13692,13968,6359,6791,7243,7140,~6982,7220,13683,13969,6357,6788,7237,7129,~7035,7227,13665,13961,6359,6805,7249,7103,~6935,7223,13682,13995,6383,6835,7273,7116,~6868,7210,13706,14000,6402,6854,7288,7129,~6972,7224,13676,13976,6367,6825,7255,7103,~6987,7233,13664,13974,6369,6820,7237,7098,~6985,7219,13657,13966,6379,6828,7245,7089,~6951,7229,13675,13999,6402,6861,7288,7102,~6935,7241,13679,14002,6403,6861,7285,7096,~6909,7200,13685,14004,6407,6855,7275,7085,~6966,7219,13661,13995,6390,6848,7265,7080,~6965,7212,13664,14006,6402,6868,7285,7080,~6848,7401,14181,13475,6253,6692,7231,6960,~6935,7437,14160,13458,6241,6700,7234,6941,~6931,7431,14160,13458,6244,6709,7240,6938,~6910,7417,14159,13461,6246,6712,7237,6930,~6892,7421,14165,13484,6259,6715,7250,6937,~6899,7428,14155,13484,6256,6703,7252,6918,~6917,7416,14125,13453,6230,6684,7208,6888,~6927,7431,14132,13454,6221,6677,7204,6879,~6894,7431,14142,13461,6229,6697,7243,6899,~6914,7432,14132,13464,6231,6694,7233,6879,~6924,7435,14111,13462,6230,6679,7217,6885,~6951,7435,14104,13465,6210,6671,7217,6883,~6892,7432,14105,13464,6197,6650,7205,6873,~6858,7454,14098,13468,6207,6653,7194,6862,~6925,7454,14090,13471,6217,6663,7202,6856,~6945,7451,14083,13457,6221,6667,7210,6864,~6882,7442,14088,13484,6229,6659,7218,6869,~6901,7432,14073,13460,6211,6630,7197,6843,~6971,7417,14071,13462,6207,6636,7198,6843,~6913,7420,14070,13485,6231,6647,7207,6850,~6879,7442,14067,13478,6236,6654,7201,6851,~6996,7465,14053,13451,6206,6638,7191,6827,~6872,7451,14094,13496,6244,6670,7226,6862,~6890,7441,14078,13489,6246,6659,7218,6854,~6961,7465,14056,13469,6233,6638,7213,6850,~7003,7441,14042,13453,6219,6618,7200,6840,~6865,7421,14074,13506,6260,6650,7229,6864,~6861,7437,14062,13499,6243,6648,7221,6860,~6985,7465,14019,13458,6209,6617,7194,6812,~6921,7455,14046,13481,6236,6651,7223,6834,~6897,7451,14047,13472,6231,6650,7229,6830,~6928,7474,14028,13467,6223,6643,7227,6824,~6938,7434,14015,13465,6211,6636,7216,6805,~6955,7427,13997,13439,6184,6615,7194,6786,~6959,7469,13995,13441,6180,6623,7208,6796,~6999,7479,13994,13448,6176,6640,7229,6808,~6893,7468,14030,13474,6203,6682,7252,6831,~6876,7493,14030,13479,6216,6690,7252,6834,~6956,7498,14004,13457,6206,6673,7237,6817,~6925,7478,14016,13464,6209,6660,7223,6818,~6910,7451,14025,13469,6214,6643,7208,6811,~6979,7474,14018,13471,6211,6636,7208,6805,~6941,7474,14008,13461,6220,6643,7201,6807,~6859,7462,14042,13488,6237,6673,7218,6815,~6901,7441,14035,13492,6250,6684,7224,6805,~6959,7457,14032,13476,6241,6656,7208,6780,~6940,7458,14042,13464,6227,6651,7189,6762,~6948,7474,14047,13464,6219,6646,7175,6743,~Bv:3,Ld:0000000000,Pm:0,Hs:1,gain1,cld:0,BPM:76,#*#</ECG data><device_id>SD2018G1V1R100139</device_id><client_id>65</client_id>
```

Here is the code that I did so far:

```
def findHighPeaks(A,count):
pivots   = [i for a,(i,b),c in zip(A,enumerate(A[1:],1),A[2:])
                            if a>b and b<c or a<b and b>c]
iWaves = [(left,mid,right) for left,mid,right
                           in  zip([0]+pivots,pivots,pivots[1:]+[len(A)-1])]
peaks  = [(A[left],A[mid],A[right]) for left,mid,right in iWaves
                                    if A[left]<A[mid]]
highPeaks = set(sorted(peaks,key=lambda p:p[1])[-count:])
return [p for p in peaks if p in highPeaks]

import re
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
f=open( "D:/NR/Ganesh_ECG_20190523/ECG20190523115005.sh","r" )
Raw_file=f.read()
start_data=Raw_file.find("<ECG data>")+len("<ECG data>")
end_data=Raw_file.find("</ECG data>")
Sorted_data=Raw_file[start_data:end_data]
A=Sorted_data
x = re.split('~|#\*#', A)
lead_2_data= [list(filter(None, i.split(","))) for i in x if  ":" not in i]
Device_data = [list(filter(None, i.split(","))) for i in x if  ":" in i]
ECG_data=([x for x in lead_2_data if x])
array=[list (i)for i in zip(*ECG_data)]
lead_2=(array[1])
A = list(map(int, lead_2))
Q,R,S = zip(*findHighPeaks(A,13))
print("R=",R)
print("Q=",Q)
print("S=",S)
```

How it is possible to find P,T peaks. Is there any method. Kindy comment below

(Note: The data that is given above is the data in file that is mentioned in program, I have deleted some data in the file since the text limit is upto 30000 characters )

Comment: Have you tried using NeuroKit2 package for python? It has functions for locating P, Q, S and T waves in ECG signals. I'll leave a link for it here : https://neurokit2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/ecg_delineate.html

Comment: Yeah @SørenGroveVejlstrup I have already tried it. but it returns just the peaks in a graph, I need those values too . And it is not accurate. Even though I am going to give another shot.

Comment: I am afraid that unless you explain the logic needed to identify a P or T peak, your ability to get help from the broad base of support available on SO, is rather limited.  Also, It would be useful to explain why you believe the NeiroKit2 results are insufficiently accurate for your purposes.

Comment: Have you plotted the data? It's not pretty. There is not sufficient resolution to find anything except the R peaks. Any finer structure is missing. The R peaks are so wide, they are wiping out the Q and S points. R rate is 73 bpm --> 1.217 beats/second --> .822 sec/beat. Beats occur approx every 8 points. That puts the time between data points at 0.1 seconds per data point or a data rate of 10 Hz. Data rate should be faster by a factor of 10.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [findpeaks](https://erdogant.github.io/findpeaks) library for this issue that I developed. It is designed to detect peaks and valleys in different kinds of data. I tried to test it on your data but between the values, there are many other strings such as Pm:0,Hs:1,gain1,cld:0. I'm not sure what to do with that. But there is enough [documentation](https://erdogant.github.io/findpeaks) that can help you do it yourself.

Small example:

```
pip install findpeaks

x = [7193,7539,14310,14364,7414,7353,...,7231,7108]
fp = findpeaks(method="peakdetect")
results = fp.fit(x)

# All peaks and valleys can be found here:
results['df']

# Plot the results
fp.plot()
```